# I want to append some text into new list until list meets specific strings

Tags: python, text, data-science

I'm pre-processing trump-hillary debate script text to create 3 lists which will including each 3 person's saying.
Entire script is 1046 lists

some of text are as following

```
for i in range(len(loaded_txt)):
    print("load_text[i]",load_text[i])
```

---

loaded_txt[i] TRUMP: No, it's going to totally help you. And one thing we have to do: Repeal and replace the disaster known as Obamacare. It's destroying our country. It's destroying our businesses, our small business and our big businesses. We have to repeal and replace Obamacare.

loaded_txt[i]

loaded_txt[i] You take a look at the kind of numbers that that will cost us in the year '17, it is a disaster. If we don't repeal and replace -- now, it's probably going to die of its own weight. But Obamacare has to go. It's -- the premiums are going up 60 percent, 70 percent, 80 percent. Next year they're going to go up over 100 percent.

loaded_txt[i]

loaded_txt[i] And I'm really glad that the premiums have started -- at least the people see what's happening, because she wants to keep Obamacare and she wants to make it even worse, and it can't get any worse. Bad health care at the most expensive price. We have to repeal and replace Obamacare.

loaded_txt[i]

loaded_txt[i] WALLACE: And, Secretary Clinton, same question, because at this point, Social Security and Medicare are going to run out, the trust funds are going to run out of money. Will you as president entertain -- will you consider a grand bargain, a deal that includes both tax increases and benefit cuts to try to save both programs?

---

I tried to append list into TRUMP_script_list=[], if it has "TRUMP:" in list like this

```
TRUMP_script_list=[]

for i in range(len(loaded_txt)):
    if "TRUMP:" in loaded_txt[i]:
        TRUMP_script_list.append(loaded_txt[i])
```

But the problem is list without name.
But text without name should be trump's saying if it is under text with name of trump, UNTIL list meets texts including names not trump(wallace or clinton)

I tried "while" loop which will be terminated if list would contain other names(wallace, clinton). But failed to implement.

How can I implement this algorithm or any other good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define function to get title:

```
def get_title(text, titles, previous_title):
    for title in titles:
        if title in text:
            return title
    return previous_title
```

define reference dictionary:

```
name_script_list = {'TRUMP:':TRUMP_script_list, 'HILLARY:':HILLARY_script_list, 'WALLACE:':WALLACE_script_list}
titles = set(name_script_list.keys())
title = ''
```

iterate through list in for loop:

```
for text in loaded_txt:
    title = get_title(text, titles, title)
    name_script_list[title].append(text)
```

basically the idea is that get_title() gets a series of titles to try, as well as what the last title was. If any of the titles appear, it returns that one. Otherwise, it returns the prior title

I initialized the initial title as `''`. This will work, so long as there is a title in the first line of text. If there isn't, it will throw an error. The fix for this is up to how you want it implemented. Do you just not want to consider such a case (indicates error in loaded_txt, or list of possible titles)? Do you want to set a specific person's name as the default initial title? Do you want to skip lines until the initial title? There are a number of approaches, and I'm not sure which you would prefer

Comment: Thanks for beautiful algorithm. It works well. Do you think it's bad idea to use while loop for this case or do you think it's impossible to implement this same algorithm with while loop? If it's possible way, I'll try it.

Comment: It should be possible, but I think it would end up being more complicated. You have a set number of objects (text's in loaded_text or speak names) that don't change. For loops are designed for iterating through a set list of objects